# "additional #using directories" property in cmake CMakeList.txt

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, cmake

I cant seem to find the way to set the visual studio property "additional #using directories" from my cmake CMakeList.txt file when using cmake to generate VS solution files.

Its a CLI/cpp project.

Here is my current build file:

```
set(the_description "My CLI Project")

ocv_define_module(tiling opencv_stitching)


set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES "System;System.Core")
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/clr /EHa")
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX "d")

if(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG MATCHES "/RTC1")
   string(REPLACE "/RTC1" " " CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
endif()

if(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS MATCHES "/EHsc")
   string(REPLACE "/EHsc" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
endif()

message(STATUS ${the_module})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set these via the [`/AI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1x72k9t%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) compiler option.  For example with CMake version >= 2.8.12 you could use [`target_compile_options`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_options.html):

```
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
                       $<$<BOOL:${MSVC}>:/AI${MetadataDir1}
                                         /AI${MetadataDir2}>)
```