# Is there a way to skip /AI switch, when we add dependency of C# library to C++ target?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, cmake

I'm setting up some Visual Studio Solution, where I have some C# and C++ projects. I wonder if I can somehow simplify the CMake code which manages the dependency between the C++ target and the C# library.

It should work on Visual Studio 2015 with CMake 3.15. On this [page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/release/3.8.html#c) I read that the `target_link_libraries` function should work the same for C++ and C# targets.

Old solution:

```
target_link_libraries(C++Target LINKING_TYPE CSharpLibrary)
target_compile_options(C++Target LINKING_TYPE "/AI${PATH_TO_DIR_WITH_CSHARP_DLL}")
```

Desired solution:

```
target_link_libraries(C++Target LINKING_TYPE CSharpLibrary)
```

Summary of results:
With old solution everything works properly, but to make it in this way I must have some "if" construction in my CMake to detect that added library is C# library.

When I make it in this desired way I get compilation error.

```
foo.cpp(10): fatal error C1107: could not find assembly 'C#Library.dll': please specify the assembly search path using /AI or by setting the LIBPATH environment variable
```

So I wonder if there is some way of simplifying this dependency adding? Maybe I can set some property of C#Library?

**Update after comment of [squareskittles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3987854/squareskittles):**

My if-construction looks like this

```
if(NOT IS_IMPORTED)
    if(DEPENDENCY_LANGUAGE STREQUAL CSharp)
        target_compile_options(${TARGET} ${LINKING_TYPE} "/AI${PATH_TO_DIR_WITH_CSHARP_DLL}")
    endif(DEPENDENCY_LANGUAGE STREQUAL CSharp)
endif(NOT IS_IMPORTED)
```

and of course I can use generator expressions, but I really don't know if it is human readable

```
target_compile_options(${TARGET} ${LINKING_TYPE} "$<$<AND:$<STREQUAL:${DEPENDENCY_LANGUAGE},CSharp>,$<NOT:$<BOOL:IS_IMPORTED>>>:/AI${IMPORT_DIR}>")
```

if-constructions seems to be more clear solution, than that.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, there is no mature way for C# assemblies to expose native functions to be called by C++ code. Is your C++ project referencing C# projects by C++/CLI? If so, it is coupled with MS C++ that there is no reason to use cmake-based project instead of msbuild-based project.

Comment: Can you expand your question post to include the `if`-construction portion of your CMake? It is possible you could use generator expressions (`BOOL`) to conditionally add the path to the C# DLL. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24194745/3987854) answer.